# stop background music when embed video start in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am using UIWebView to play embed video from youtube, and my problem is how can i call a method when the embed video starts to play?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution myself so if anyone want it here it is:

in `- (void)viewDidLoad` add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoStrated:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

and add:

```
-(void)videoStrated:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"video started");
}
```

in implemention file